# Permission denied when trying to run C++ application

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

I am new to C++. I built code from a repo using this command:

`g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -I/Users/asi/anaconda3/pkgs/libopencv-3.4.2-h7c891bd_1/include   -c -o RPPG.o RPPG.cpp -o Heartbeat`

There were no errors. However, when I run:

`$ ./Heartbeat`

I get the error:
`-bash: ./Heartbeat: Permission denied`

I am on a Mac. What am I doing wrong?

## EDIT

I removed -c -o RPPG.o, so that the command is now:

`g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -I/Users/asi/anaconda3/pkgs/libopencv-3.4.2-h7c891bd_1/include   RPPG.cpp -o Heartbeat`

But that gives me this error (i removed a bunch of the middle output as it was too big to post:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

      RPPG::extractSignal_xminay() in RPPG-297942.o
      cv::Mat_<double>::operator=(cv::Mat&&) in RPPG-297942.o
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Remove `-c` and `-o RPPG.o` from the compiler command line.  You have a conflicting set of flags there.

Comment: This didn't work, see edit

Comment: now you have to specify how to link this library: so add `-L<path where lib is> -l<lib name>`. Note that `<lib name>` is not same as file name of it.

Comment: I would recommend you to learn use some build manager, like `cmake`. Lots of building stuff will be automated.

Comment: I don't see you linking to opencv libraries for this one: `cv::Mat_<double>::operator=(cv::Mat&&) in RPPG-297942.o`

Comment: `RPPG::extractSignal_xminay() in RPPG-297942.o` is confusing because you appear to be compiling RRPG.cpp. Not sure what this is about.

Comment: @MarekR I do not understand your suggestion about how to link library. What command should I enter?

Comment: You have to figure out what libraries your code needs. His instruction was the arguments to use once you figure that out.

Comment: Probably one is -lopencv_core however there are several other opencv libraries that may be used.